# Android animateCamera GoogleMap.CancelableCallback Usage

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm totally stumped on how to use the callback feature of "animateCamera" in android SDK.

I want to use the onFinish feature, thankyou.

**public final void animateCamera (CameraUpdate update, GoogleMap.CancelableCallback callback)**

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera%28com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.CancelableCallback.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No worries, i cant believe the moment i post this after looking for ages i find an example in the google play maps api samples that shows it....:

sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps\src\com\example\mapdemo\CameraDemoActivity.java

```
changeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(SYDNEY), 
        new CancelableCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Animation to Sydney complete", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Animation to Sydney canceled", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```